# WP7 Change Application Name

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have created an application and I am about to launch it to the marketplace. I want to change the name of the application.

Can anyone tell me how I can do this please?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You change the Title of the app in the file called WMAppmanifest.xml.
Inside the App-tag theres a field for Title.